# Looking for algorithm that partition a matrix given a criterion with restriction on the number of operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Context:**

Be a vector $V \in \mathbb{R}^p$, a matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{(p\times p)}$ and a second vector $B\in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that

$V =X B$

I'm looking for a way to find a partition of the type
$\begin{pmatrix}
V_a\\
V_b
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
X_{a} & X_{ab}\\
X_{ba} & X_b
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
B_a\\
B_b
\end{pmatrix}$

with dimention
$
\begin{pmatrix}
k \times 1\\
(p-k)\times 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
k\times k & k\times(p-k)\\
(p-k)\times k & (p-k) \times (p-k)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
k\times 1\\
(p-k)\times 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Knowing that this partition must minimize $||V_b-X_{ba} X_a^{-1}V_a||$
and that $X_a$ is invertible by assumption.

**Question :**

Knowing that (1) $p$ is very large (at least $10^6$ and (2) that I have a theoretical restriction on the number of operation: maximum $K\times log(p) $ operations.

Do you know any algorithm that would allow me to find numericaly the partition i'm interested in ?

And if not:
 do you know in which (sub)field of sciences I should pursue my research ? Any authors ?

Thanks a lot for the time you spend reading this.

Mathieu

Comment: @Mathieu: I can make an educated as to your context, but would you perhaps add a few words on this. In particular, which properties ensure that $X_a$ is nonsingular regardless of the choice of $p$. Moreover, I do not understand which quantity you wish to minimize! Is it some norm of the vector $V_b - X_{ba} X_a^{-1} V_a$ or something else? I simply do not know what you mean that you wish to minimize this vector.

Comment: You are right, my question is not well defined. $X_a$ is invertible by assumption and your intuition is right, I would like to minimize the norm. I'm going to edit this right away. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: @CarlChristian (first comment was also for you). I want to min $||V_b-X_{ba} X_a^{-1}V_a||$, because, with an ideal case I'm looking for a partition such that $V_b=X_{ba} X_a^{-1}V_a$. Moreover I do not know if I should use L1 or L2 norm.

Comment: I am both intrigued about your underlying application and extremely skeptical the feasibility of what you are trying to accomplish :) If such a partition could be found easily, then it would have profound implications in the field of parallel (sparse) solvers, because the Schur complement system $(X_b - X_{ba} X_a^{-1} X_{ab}) z = V_b - X_{ba}X_a^{-1} V_a$ would have the trivial solution $z=0$. Your restriction on the number of operations is probably impossible to meet unless there are other conditions. Do you have any other conditions on the matrix? Perhaps it has a special sparsity pattern?

Comment: @CarlChristian About the condition on the matrix, I have one : $(X_{ab}X_{ba})$ is invertible. I do not have assumed anything more because I wanned to be as general as I was able to be, but I'm free to do so. Then if you think that assuming some sparsity pattern would make the problem easier in a first time, I'm very interested. Again, thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: Is there some kind of continuity involved, i.e. can the entries of $x_{ij}$ of the matrix be written as $x_{ij} = f(i,j)$ for some continuous function? If they are simple "random", then I do not see how we can possibly hope to succeed, but if there is continuity involved, then there are optimization methods which can be applied.